# C# - Using Directory.EnumerateDirectories depth first?

Tags: c#

It's really as simple as the title suggests. I want to go through a directory and all sub directories and get the files (which I currently can do), however the problem lies with sub-directory files appearing after all the top directory files. So if I have the folders Alfa, Bravo, Charlie, Delta, and in Alfa is Echo, the contents will be shown as Alfa files, Bravo files, Charlie files, Delta files, Echo files. Which is breadth first, is there a way to change it to Depth first.

Currently using the method in the title Directory.EnumerateDirectories, with the string, string, searchoption constructor. If not I presume I shall have to go through them recursively.

Comment: You could get them all and sort the resulting dataset in whatever way you want.

Comment: For the size of the folder structure and information that needs to be taken out I think it would end up being easier to rewrite the program using a recursive algorithm. Although I did not think of that so thanks!

Comment: I would go with my own recursive algorithm if this requirement is really important.

Comment: Do you have a *lot* (tens of thousands) of files or is the actual deferred execution part of it an integral part of your algorithm? Because rolling your own algorithm just because you don't want to add an `.OrderBy()` to your function call seems excessive.

Comment: There is quite a bit of information gathering to be done and then excel writing per file. Not so much tens of thousands I think it's probably under ten thousands for all files. With your suggestion I would create the list then order it then iterate through correct?

Comment: Correct. You iterate through it anyway, I'd guess. You just have to sort it between creating it an iterating it.

Comment: @nvoigt used something slightly different to what you suggested but it works and without your pointer I wouldn't have gotten there. Used this dirs.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x, y)); if you can post as an answer due to your integral part to my answer I'll upvote and mark correct for anyone else trying the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can afford to put a list of all files in memory and you don't need the deferred execution of the enumeration, you can materialize your enumeration first by using `.ToList()` or `ToArray()` and then sort it according to your needs by using `.OrderBy()` or the Lists `.Sort()` method. Then you can proceed in your application with the list of paths ordered like you want it to be ordered.